# How can I make a goal optional in maven?

Tags: maven

I'm trying to integrate [sonarqube](http://sonarqube.org) to my project build. The build command I run is:

```
mvn clean package sonar:sonar
```

The 'sonar:sonar' is the sonarqube goal. I've setup sonarqube at a remote server, so, this goal communicates with that server to analyse my code. But this is causing the build to fail if the server is offline or if I'm offline.

How can I make this particular goal optional so that if this fails it doesn't stop the build process?

Comment: You can always have the `-fae` flag to only fail the build at the end... This plugin doesn't offer a way to disregard the errors.

Comment: if the goal is not bound to a phase via an execution configured in the pom.xml it will not execute by itself. So simply "mvn clean package" would be the easiest way to not execute it? Otherwise the plugin seems to have a skip parameter: https://github.com/SonarSource/sonar-scanner-maven/blob/master/src/main/java/org/sonarsource/scanner/maven/SonarQubeMojo.java - so "mvn clean package sonar:sonar -Dsonar.skip=true" might work (haven't tried). An approach I often see is to put the sonar configuration in a profile and only activate it when needed.